# Try to upload image in product with cloudinary and nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, upload

I am creating the backend of an ecommerce store and I have to validate the photos. I started with an idea, but my teacher has made me change and now I don't know how to combine what I have done with what he asks of me. Let me explain the situation: I have created a special path for uploading the image to cloudinary. This is the code:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary')
const auth = require('./../middleware/auth')
const authAdmin = require('./../middleware/authAdmin')
const fs = require('fs-extra')


// we will upload image on cloudinary
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_API_SECRET
})

// Upload image only admin can use
router.post('/upload', auth, authAdmin, (req, res) =>{
    try {
        if(!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: 'No files were uploaded.'})
        
        const file = req.files.file;
        if(file.size > 1024*1024) {
            removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "Size too large"})
        }

        if(file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/png'){
            removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "File format is incorrect."})
        }

        cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file.tempFilePath, {folder: "ecommerce"}, async(err, result)=>{
            if(err) throw err;

            removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)

            res.json({public_id: result.public_id, url: result.secure_url})
        })


    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
    }
})

// Delete image only admin can use
router.post('/destroy',auth , authAdmin, (req, res) =>{
    try {
        const {public_id} = req.body;
        if(!public_id) return res.status(400).json({msg: 'No images Selected'})

        cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(public_id, async(err, result) =>{
            if(err) throw err;

            res.json({msg: "Deleted Image"})
        })

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
    }
    
})


const removeTmp = (path) =>{
    fs.unlink(path, err=>{
        if(err) throw err;
    })
}

module.exports = router
```

I have a product model made like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    price:{
        type: Number,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    images:{
        type: Object,
        required: true
     
    },
    category:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
        required: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})


module.exports = mongoose.model("Products", productSchema)
```

And this is my function to create the product:

```
 createProduct: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const {
                name,
                price,
                images,
                description,
                categoryId
            } = req.body;
              
           

            if (!images) return res.status(400).json({
                message: "No hay imagen del producto!"
            })

            if (!(name || price || description))
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "Por favor, complete todos los campos"
                })

            const product = await Products.findOne({
                name
            })
            if (product)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "Este producto ya ha sido creado anteriormente"
                })

            const newProduct = new Products({
                name: name.toLowerCase(),
                price,
                description,
                categoryId,
                images
            })

            await newProduct.save()
            res.json({
                message: "Producto creado ! "
            })

        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: err.message
            })
        }
    },
```

And this is the route for create product :

```
app.use('/api', require('./routes/productRouter'))
router.post('/products', auth, authAdmin, productCtrl.createProduct)
```

The point is that, first, I would upload the image, and when creating the product, it would pass through Postman the results of the image upload (public_id and url).

In the review, my teacher told me to put everything together in the same route, that of creating the product, I have been trying all morning and there is no way it will work for me. Can somebody help me ? I don't know exactly what the function should look like with the integrated image.

Kind regards, thank you in advance

Comment: Just when you creating product call you route (the same witch you call by postman) and created images then put rest code of creating product.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, can you help me with these code, please ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Show full code of route witch creating images. you put only code of function but we don't know path of route. And post request witch you use in postman

Comment: I have edited now the question with all the code

Comment: Because code editor on stack sucks :( i put some hint in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-haze-t7qs4?file=/src/api/createProduct.js)  the key to your problem is use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) package Then I moved your upload code to separate file and I [promisificat](https://javascript.info/promisify) it. In upload route i use this code and in create product as well. So in route of createdProduc i put multer upload middleware and then in request we can use body and files array. You can find some link to tutorial in comments. I hope this help you.

Comment: Resolved !! Thanks a lot @Robert !!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Create Product -- Admin
exports.createProduct = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  let images = [];

  if (typeof req.body.images === "string") {
    images.push(req.body.images);
  } else {
    images = req.body.images;
  }

  const imagesLinks = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(images[i], {
      folder: "products",
    });
    imagesLinks.push({
      public_id: result.public_id,
      url: result.secure_url,
    });
  }

  req.body.images = imagesLinks;
  req.body.user = req.user.id;

  const product = await Product.create(req.body);
  res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    product,
  });
});
```